# Angular ngModelOptions - bind value to model only when button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, two-way

I have an input field that is bound to a model object, which I don't want to bind until the user clicks a button. I went through `ng-model-option` and `updateOn`, but seems they trigger only on out of the box JS events like `blur` and `focus`.

```
<input ng-model="modelobject" ng-model-options="{updateOn: confirmButtonClick}">

<button id="confirmButton" role="confirm" ng-click="confirmButtonClick == true" class="confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
```

How can I make the value bind to the model only upon the click of the button or a custom function? Would I need to write a custom directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do solve your problem by wrapping you fields inside a form and then update `ng-model` on `submit` of a form like `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"`.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="modelobject" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
  <button id="confirmButton" role="confirm" class="confirm-btn">
    Confirm
  </button>
</form>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EImF4KavtZruvgkUMkXY?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this! Thank you, that's perfect!